# How MySQL put all NEW/OLD trigger data to temporary table and use in procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, procedure, temp-tables

How to put the NEW/OLD data into temporary table without filed name.
I've tried create trigger, procedure like this but it fails:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert` AFTER INSERT
ON `master`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE after_insert_trigger_temp_table ENGINE=MEMORY 
    AS (SELECT NEW.*);
    CALL after_insert_action();
END$$
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `after_insert_action`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `slave` (`name`,`detail`)
    SELECT `name`,`detail` FROM after_insert_trigger_temp_table;
END$$
```

Answer (score 3):

You see the part where it says `FOR EACH ROW`...

> The statement following `FOR EACH ROW` defines the statement to execute each time the trigger activates, which **occurs once for each row affected** by the triggering statement.  -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html *(emphasis added)*

So you are proposing to create a new temporary table *for each row* that gets inserted into the table with the trigger, somehow accessing all of the columns with `NEW`.`*` for insertion into that table, then calling a stored procedure, and inserting into a *different* table by selecting two columns from that temporary table that presumably you know are in the original table.  At some point, the temporary table would of course need to go away because if you inserted more than 1 row into the table in one query or in one session, then you're be trying to create a temporary table with the same name as one already owned by your session.

I've never encountered OLD.* or NEW.* catchalls in triggers or the documentation, and at any rate, it's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish other than possibly avoiding typing out two column names or the ability to change what you're tracking with the stored procedure without updating this trigger.

But a key design factor you need to keep in mind with triggers is that they should do as little as possible as efficiently as possible because they have a high potential for being a performance problem if you don't stick to this rule.

A couple of alternative approaches come to mind, since the temporary table doesn't make sense based on the detail in the question:

Option 1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `master` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `slave` (`name`,`detail`) VALUES (NEW.`name`,NEW.`detail`);
END $$
```

Option 2:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `master` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    CALL after_insert_action(NEW.`name`,NEW.`detail`);
END $$


CREATE PROCEDURE `after_insert_action`(in new_name TEXT, in new_detail TEXT)
# you may want to use more appropriate datatypes instead of TEXT
# but this should work as written as long as those columns are no larger than TEXT
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `slave` (`name`,`detail`) VALUES (new_name, new_detail);
END$$
```

Comment: Hmm, Thank you for your answer.
I can't remember what I've asked but my question -it doesn't make sense at all. to create temp. table in single each row. - -"